# Referring external framework causing issue on device

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios, ios4

I am using an external framework and where ever I am using the classes of the framework, I am getting the following error:

```
".objc_class_name_<FrameWorkClassName>", referenced from:
```

I checked the header search path and library path and I am giving the correct relative path there.

One important thing is that I am able to run the code on Simulator but it is creating issue on device.

Any clue will really help?

Comment: If it works on the simulator, then I would guess that the framework you are linking against is built for the simultator and not the device. The simulator uses the i386 architecture, while the device uses the arm architecture. Make sure you have a copy of it with the arm architecture.

Comment: You were right. That was the issue.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw - post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works on the simulator, then I would guess that the framework you are linking against is built for the simultator and not the device. The simulator uses the i386 architecture, while the device uses the arm architecture. Make sure you have a copy of it with the arm architecture.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this error implies that the compiler is not able to find the referenced framework. Try cleaning all targets and make sure every framework you are using is added properly to the project. Which framework are you trying to use?